# Cut axes below zero in the axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

I am drawing a picture in the axis environment. My issue is that I would like the axes lines to end at zero and not go beyond to the left or below. However, when I set the properties xmin=ymin=0, it is not only the lines that disappear but all the drawings below them that I use to mark the important points. See the pictures below for reference.

[image] [image]

So, while I more or less understand why this happens I don't know how to erase the negative part of the axes while keeping the axes labels. Below a MWE:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames,handout,aspectratio=169]{beamer} % --> loads xcolor and hyperref

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Loaded by default in beamer (and many others...)
%\usepackage{
%   amsthm
%   color
%   enumerate
%   fourier
%   hyperref
%   xcolor
%}

\usepackage{
    fourier,            % For typesetting
    newtxtext,      % To set the fonts to Times New Roman
    import,         % to import files
    caption,            % To include captions in tables and figures
    subcaption,     % To include subcaptions in tables and figures
    graphicx,       % A more advanced package for images and figures
    float,          % Improves floating objects: figures and tables
    nicematrix,         % To make nice tables
    multicol,       % For multicolum slides
    ragged2e,       % New commands and environments for ragged tex
    mathtools,      % Loads and enhances the features of amsmath
    amssymb,            % to cross a term in an equation
    cancel,         % to cross a term in an equation
    marvosym            % Adds Marting Vogel's symbols: euro, comunicaiton,...
}                   
    
%TO BE REMOVED
    %\let\marvosymLightning\Lightning   
    %This sequence of packages controls the mathematical tools of latex
            %\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}  % to cross a term in an equation


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% GRAPH CONTROL
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{pgfplots} %--> it loads tikz, already loaded?
    \usetikzlibrary{    
        fit, 
        calc,
        matrix,
        positioning,
        arrows.meta,
        intersections,
        through,
        backgrounds,
        patterns,
        shapes,
        decorations.pathreplacing,
        arrows.meta
    }
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
    \pgfplotsset{overwrite option/.style args={#1 with #2}{#1=#2,#1/.code=}}
    \pgfplotsset{
        vasymptote/.style={before end axis/.append code={\draw[dashed,<->,-{Latex}] ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:#1,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:#1,0}); }},
        myaxis/.style={axis line style={<->, {Latex}-{Latex}}}
    }   % This fancy shit sets the arrows to both parts of the axis in the axis environment of pgfplot



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% START OF THE PRESENTATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        %------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% SUBSTITUTION AND INCOME EFFECTS
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1]
    \begin{axis}[
        width=6cm,
        xscale = 1, yscale = 1,
        axis lines = middle,
        % myaxis,
        % grid,
        % grid style={densely dashed},
        xmin = -20, xmax = 130, ymin = -25, ymax = 200,
        every axis/.append style={font=\tiny},
        xlabel = {$L$}, xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
        ylabel = $C$, ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=east},
        xtick = \empty,
        xticklabels = \empty,
        ytick = \empty,
        yticklabels = \empty,
        samples=100,
        domain=-2:10,
        % axis equal,
        % no markers
        ]
        
        % First slide
        % ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            % Functions
                \addplot[domain=0:110,       Mahogany, name path = ic0]{(90*60^(1/3))/(x^(1/3))};
                \addplot[domain=0:112,       black   , name path = bc0]{120-1/2*x};
                
                % Points
                \draw[black, thick, fill] (axis cs: 60,90) circle [ radius = .5] node[above] at (60,90) {\fontsize{5}{5} \selectfont $E_0$};
                
                % Dashed lines
                 \draw[dashed,gray, ultra thin] (90,64)--(112,64) node[above,xshift = 5] at (90,60) {\fontsize{4}{4} \selectfont $w$};
                \draw[dashed,gray, ultra thin] (60,0)--(60,90) node[below] at (60,0) {\fontsize{4}{4} \selectfont $L^*$};
                \draw[dashed,gray, ultra thin] (0,90)--(60,90) node[left, xshift = 2] at (0,90) {\fontsize{4}{4} \selectfont $C^*=C'$};
                \draw[dashed,gray, ultra thin] (112,0)--(112,200);
        
                % Arrows
                \draw[-latex, ultra thin] (120,27)--(120,0) node[above, yshift=-5, xshift=-1] at (120,32) {\fontsize{4}{4} \selectfont $R$};
                \draw[-latex, ultra thin] (120,37)--(120,64);
        
                \draw[-latex, ultra thin] (51,-20)--(0,-20) node[above, yshift=-5, xshift=-1] at (56,-20) {\fontsize{4}{4} \selectfont $T$};
                \draw[-latex, ultra thin] (61,-20)--(112,-20);
        
                \draw[-latex, ultra thin] (-10,55)--(-10,0) node[above, yshift=-7, xshift=-1] at (-10,65) {\fontsize{4}{4} \selectfont $V$};
                \draw[-latex, ultra thin] (-10,65)--(-10,120);
                
                % Solid lines
                \draw[black, ultra thin] (117,64)--(123,64);
        
                \draw[black, ultra thin] (0,-17)--(0,-23);
                \draw[black, ultra thin] (112,-17)--(112,-23);
        
                \draw[black, ultra thin] (-13,0)--(-7,0);
                \draw[black, ultra thin] (-13,120)--(-7,120);
                
            
        % Second slide
        % ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
            % Functions
            \only<2->{ \addplot[domain=0:110,        Mahogany, name path = ic0]{(132*44^(1/3))/(x^(1/3))};}
            \only<2->{ \addplot[domain=0:112,        black   , name path = bc0]{176-x};}
                
                % Points
            \draw<2->[black, thick, fill] (axis cs: 44,132) circle [ radius = .5] node[above] at (44,132) {\fontsize{5}{5} \selectfont $E_1$};
            
            % Dashed lines
            \draw<2->[dashed,gray, ultra thin] (44,0)--(44,132) node[below] at (44,0) {\fontsize{4}{4} \selectfont $L_1$};
            \draw<2->[dashed,gray, ultra thin] (0,132)--(44,132) node[left, xshift = 2] at (0,132) {\fontsize{4}{4} \selectfont $C_1$};
                
                
        % Third slide
        % ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            
            % Functions
                \only<3->{ \addplot[domain=10:50,        Mahogany, name path = ic0, draw opacity = .5]{(90*30^(1/3))/(x^(1/3))};}
                \only<3->{ \addplot[domain=0:112,        black   , name path = bc0, draw opacity = .5]{120-x} node[right, xshift = -4] at (112,8) {\fontsize{4}{4} \selectfont $R_c$};}
                
                % Points
                \draw<3->[black, thick, fill] (axis cs: 30,90) circle [ radius = .5] node[above,yshift = -2] at (30,90) {\fontsize{4}{4} \selectfont $E'$};
                
                % Dashed lines
                \draw<3->[dashed,gray, ultra thin] (30,0)--(30,90) node[below] at (30,0) {\fontsize{4}{4} \selectfont $L'$};                                    
                \draw<3->[dashed,gray, ultra thin] (0,90)--(30,90);
        
        
        % Fourth slide
        % ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            
            % Functions
            \only<4->{ \addplot[domain=0:112,        black   , name path = bc0, draw opacity = .5]{120*2^(1/4)-x};}
                
            % Points
            \draw<4->[black, thick, fill] (axis cs: 35.676,107.0286) circle [ radius = .5] node[above] at (35.676,107.0286) {\fontsize{4}{4} \selectfont $E''$};
            
            % Dashed lines
            \draw<4->[dashed,gray, ultra thin] (35.676,0)--(35.676,107.0286) node[below] at (35.676,0) {\fontsize{4}{4} \selectfont $L''$};                                 
            \draw<4->[dashed,gray, ultra thin] (0,107.0286)--(35.676,107.0286) node[left, xshift = 2] at (0,107.0286) {\fontsize{4}{4} \selectfont $C''$};
        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to the drawing of interest, WHILE providing all lines need for a compile. May be you should also include a screenshot, and perhaps a sketch of the desired result?

Comment: If necessary, you can set the bounding box yourself, but that's a lot of unnecessary code to test with.

Comment: @MS-SPO I have modified the MWE and included pictures, hope this helps

Comment: Have you try `clip mode=individual,` pgfplots documentation section 4.21. SYMBOLIC COORDINATES AND USER TRANSFORMATIONS p.387

Comment: @pascal974, It worked!!!!